# Page Templates Drop Down Select for Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

I have a custom post type called location. I would like to be able to use 2 different templates for this custom post type and select it via the page attributes box. I have a template set up and can select it when I'm editing a Page, but not when I am editing a custom post type. I can't find any information on how to enable this. I want to enable the dropdown select for all the custom post types, not just one.

Comment: template exists only for post type `page`. for custom post type you have to do everything by yourself : creating the metabox in the backoffice, saving the value et generating the public page with the selected template

Comment: Thanks, that's given me an idea. I can pull in a template part depending on the category selected.

Answer (score 5):

Since WordPress version 4.7 **Post-Type-Templates are enabled** in the WordPress core.

That means that you can **create multiple templates for the single post-type view** as for pages.

For this you just need to edit the single post/type template, and add something like this to the top of the file:

```
/*
Template Name: Custom Type Template 
Template Post Type: post, product, custom-type 
*/
```

On the line `Template Post Type` you just add your custom post type slug.
So this template will be available on the `post`, `product` and `custom-type` post type.

I already answered this [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/255021/88895).
Read more about post-type-templates of WP 4.7 [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/03/post-type-templates-in-4-7/).

Answer (score 0):

Ok as mmm has pointed out that I can't do the dropdown select of templates on custom post types I have put this code in my single-cpt.php

```
global $post; 
if ( ( $post->post_type == 'location' ) && has_term( 'news', 'highlights' ) ) { 
include('templates/template_feature_highlight_layout.php'); 
}
```