# Multiple Single Post templates

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, template-hierarchy

I have a custom post type called funerals and a page the lists all the posts part of that custom post type.  To display a single page I create a file called single-funerals.php and that all works well.  But, now I need to have another single post page that only displays a video for a funeral.  How would I set that up and link to it from the main page that lists all the posts?

Answer (score 10):

As I answered [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/254772/how-to-add-page-attribute-template-to-custom-post/254781#254781), since WordPress 4.7 Post-Type-Templates are enabled in the WordPress core.

That means that you can create multiple templates for the single post-type view. You create these templates like you would create a normal page template. But you need to add a little more code to these templates:

```
/*
Template Name: Funerals Video Template 
Template Post Type: post, funerals 
*/
```

So you will need to copy your `single-funerals.php` file, rename it, add some code like the above to the top of the file.

After this, you should see a template select box on the post and funerals edit-screen. (because I specified these 2 post-types with `Template Post Type: post, funerals`)

Read more about post-type-templates [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/03/post-type-templates-in-4-7/).

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't know this existed. This should the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn the single-funerals.php code into a 'page template', then use that template when you create the page.

Read about page templates here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-templates/

Comment: I'm not understanding your response..

Answer (score 0):

you can create Post Type Templates It's default WordPress directories file. 
For More information:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/

single-{post_type}.php create this file where your single.php file

```
single-{post_type}.php
```