# Associate page w/ specific single post template?

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template, single

I'm working on a site that uses two different pages to filter lists of posts associated with the same custom post type ("media"), and both pages have their own templates-- a more general page named `page-media.php` and one that's more narrowly focused via taxonomy, `page-music-library.php`. While both of these pages filter lists of posts of the "media" custom post type, I would like each to render the posts in a different `single-` view when the post titles are clicked. For the main `page-media.php` template, I created a `single-media.php` template for single post views associated with that page. However, I'm not quite sure how to define an alternate `single-` view associated with the `page-music-library.php` template?

I'm seeing from [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/254845/multiple-single-post-templates) and elsewhere that as of WP 4.7, "Post Type Templates" can offer more flexibility in this way, but I'm not clear on whether that feature would apply to my situation. Thanks for any insight here, and please let me know if my objective is unclear in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Well one approach would be to create a generic `single-media.php` file and put a condition inside it which checks for the specific taxonomy. Then you would be able to include the other two based on the condition.

So, create the main template - `single-media.php` and the other two templates `page-media.php` and `page-music-library.php`. Then you could check for the the specific 
 taxonomy in this file and include the corresponding file based on the condition.

a simple example of  `single-media.php` would be

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Single Media
Template Post Type: post, media 
*/


//header and stuff


if ( has_term( $term, $taxonomy, $post ) ) {

    include '{path}/page-music-library.php';
else {
    include '{path}/page-media.php' ;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response- this seems like a good approach. Is there a way, however, to distinguish the view based on the page from which it originated? Thus, if viewing a single post via `page-media.php`, it would display one single view, and if viewing via `page-music-library.php` it would display an alternate single view?

Comment: Well if you just want to open that particular template when someone clicks on the title, then you could simply redirect the user using the wp_redirect($url) function.

Comment: @nickpish take a look at this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/custom-page-template-page-based-on-url-rewrite--wp-30564) as well, it uses the add_rewrite_rule to redirect a page template based on that.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a rewrite endpoint, which can be appended onto the end of single media permalinks to identify which requests should get the alternate template.

---

### Step 1, add the endpoint:

```
function wpd_rewrite_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'music-library', EP_PERMALINK );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_rewrite_endpoint' );
```

After adding the above code to a plugin or your theme's `functions.php` file, visit the Settings > Permalinks page to flush rewrite rules.

Assuming your permalink for a media post is:

```
http:example.com/media/my-media-post/
```

You should now also be able to visit the URL with endpoint and see the same view:

```
http:example.com/media/my-media-post/music-library/
```

---

### Step 2, add a `single_template` filter:

```
function wpd_single_template( $template ) {
    global $wp_query;
    // if this is a media post
    // AND the media-library endpoint is present,
    // load the alternate template
    if( 'media' == get_post_type( get_queried_object() )
        && isset( $wp_query->query_vars['music-library'] ) ){
            $template = locate_template( 'single-music-library.php' );
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'wpd_single_template' );
```

After adding the above code to your plugin or theme's `functions.php`, the original URL will continue to load your `single-media.php` template, while any URLs containing the endpoint will load the `single-music-library.php` template.

In both cases, the canonical URL will point to the original URL, so only that single version will be indexed by search engines, avoiding duplicate content issues.

The last step will be to modify your `page-music-library.php` template to add `music-library/` after the permalinks for each media post.

Comment: thank you for the thorough answer- I didn't realize this would be as involved. If we pare this down a bit and I simply wanted to display a different return link on the `single-` post page depending on how one reached that post-- i.e. "Return to Media Library" (`page-media.php`) or "Return to Music Library" (`page-music-library.php`) is this possible with a simple if/else statement in the `single-` page? Basically just guiding them back from whence they came...